# How to detect if autohidden taskbar is visible or not?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, taskbar

At the moment I need to detect in C++/Qt if a taskbar, which is set to "autohide" is visible on the screen or not. I have tried already following solution, unfortunately with no success:

1. Checked the autohide state with uState = (UINT) SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, pabd), this only returns whether autohide property is set or not
2. Getting work area with SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &rectWorkArea, 0); Unfortunately the work area is always of size of the entire screen, when taskbar is set to "autohiden", even if it is actually visible on the screen
3. Geting AppBarData with SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, &abd); With this function I can get both size and coordinates of the taskbar, however they are always returned as if the taskbar is being visible, even if it is hidden.

So with those methods I cannot tell, whether taskbar with "autohide" on is at given moment visible on the screen or not :-(

I would appreciate any help :-)

Comment: Hum, I don't know why, but this looks like the kind of code that could end up in a Raymond Chen blog post. Why do you need to know this information ? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: For what do you need to know if the taskbar is visible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HWND hTaskbarWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
bool isVisible = IsWindowVisible(hTaskbarWnd);
```

or

```
bool IsTaskbarWndVisible() {
HWND hTaskbarWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);
HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hTaskbarWnd , MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
MONITORINFO info = { sizeof(MONITORINFO) };
if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &info))
{
  RECT rect;
  GetWindowRect(hTaskbarWnd , &rect);
  if ((rect.top >= info.rcMonitor.bottom - 4) ||
      (rect.right <= 2) ||
      (rect.bottom <= 4) ||
      (rect.left >= info.rcMonitor.right - 2))
  return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Does this handle the case of tasbar on left/right/top of screen?