# How can I be notified when the taskbar is shown or hidden?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a Winapi window with D3D content drawn in client area. I need to be able to detect the moment when the taskbar is shown/hidden if autohiding is enabled. I thought WndProc function would receive a message on such event, but I couldn't find any info about it. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is quite probably [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085381/how-to-detect-if-autohidden-taskbar-is-visible-or-not

Comment: Why do you need to detect that? Why do you care where I CHOSE to put my taskbar? Do you handle the case of taskbar on left/right/top of screen?

Comment: @RedX I don't see anything in the question that indicates that mag_zbc cares *where* the taskbar is located. That said, "why would you need to know" is still pertinent.

Answer (score -1):

I can certainly imagine that there is a notification somehow, but I don't know for sure. However what I could suggest is to call `FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL)` to get the window handle of the taskbar it self. Then you could install a global hook or shell hook with `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: Window hooks are horribly overused.

Comment: That is no reason for down voting. It is the only way to detect hiding of the taskbar without polling.

Comment: There's a reason why hooks aren't part of the Windows Runtime - they're security (and performance) holes waiting to happen.

Comment: Many components are not part of the Windows Runtime, this is not a reason. I'm sure Microsoft has well designed the hook concept, there is no greater security vulnerability than it already is anyway. The only point that remains is performance. However this is relative. If the requirement (I don't say that the concept is good) is that detection of hiding toolbar is essentiel than this is the only solution.