# QDesktopWidget and windows taskbar

Tags: qt, taskbar

I need to have app running in fullscreen mode.

For that I used QDesktopWidget. When windows taskbar is lock it work fine.

Problems start when taskbar is in auto-hide mode. 
I cannot find any way to receive information (signal), that taskbar size on desktop changed, 
so I cannot react and change my widget size.

Is there any way to obtain information that windows taskbar changing from hidden to visible or opposite?

I would be glad about any hints.
  Marek

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if autohidden taskbar is visible or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085381/how-to-detect-if-autohidden-taskbar-is-visible-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you use `QDesktopWidget` for running in fullscreen mode! You can simply set your `MainWindow` state to fullscreen by :

```
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Comment: Or just use `showFullScreen()` which implicitly set the state when the window is shown.

Comment: Both ways (Qt::WindowFullScreen and showFullScreen() ) do not work correctly in my case. My question was: "how obtain information that windows taskbar changing ?" not "is there other way" :) Anyway thx