# how detect that taskbar switched status from hidden to show

Tags: qt

Windows taskbar may have status "Auto-hide".

Does anybody know how detect using QT that windows taskbar is during animation?

If this is not possible, maybe there is way to detect that taskbar switched status from hidden to show or opposite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if autohidden taskbar is visible or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085381/how-to-detect-if-autohidden-taskbar-is-visible-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to changes to the taskbar(not only on auto hide, but also at user move and/or resize of the taskbar) in Qt you can do something like this:

```
void MainWindow::workAreaResized()
{
    //Get handle of taskbar
    HWND hTaskbarWnd = FindWindow(TEXT("Shell_TrayWnd"), NULL);

    //Get info about screen that the taskbar lives
    HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hTaskbarWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    MONITORINFO info = {sizeof(MONITORINFO)};

    if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &info))
    {
        //Get taskbar rect info
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hTaskbarWnd, &rect);

        //Calculate screen size
        int screenwidth = info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left;
        int screenheight = info.rcMonitor.bottom - info.rcMonitor.top;

        //Calculate top-left position
        int left = qMax(info.rcMonitor.left, rect.left);
        int top = qMax(info.rcMonitor.top, rect.top);

        //Calculate taskbar rectangle visible on the screen
        QRegion taskbar = QRegion(left, top, qMin((LONG)screenwidth, rect.right) - left, qMin((LONG)screenheight, rect.bottom) - top);

        //Get a rectangle of the screen
        QRegion screen = QRegion(info.rcMonitor.left, info.rcMonitor.top, screenwidth, screenheight);

        //Get the available area rect (the screen rectangle subtracted the taskbar rectangle)
        QRect workarea = screen.subtracted(taskbar).rects().first();

        //If work area is different than the actual window rectangle, move and/or resize it
        if (workarea.topLeft() != pos() || workarea.size() != size())
        {
            move(workarea.topLeft());
            resize(workarea.width() - (frameGeometry().width() - width()),
                   workarea.height() - (frameGeometry().height() - height()));
        }
    }
}
```

Call that function and the variable `QRect workarea` will contain the available area on the screen that the taskbar lives, at the moment you call that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108(v=vs.85).aspx) ABM_GETSTATE to get the state of the taskbar.